# Order of array content is not consistent in JSON response

Tags: node.js, express, es6-promise, knex.js

So, I have this nested set table in Postgres, [here's the schema and data](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/a20af). And I have this controller function code below in my Express app to get the nested category as an array using Knex and some promise handling:

```
const getCategories = (req, res, db) => {
  const products = []

  db.raw(`
    SELECT child.id, child.name, child.path
    FROM product_category parent
    JOIN product_category child
    ON child.lower BETWEEN parent.lower AND parent.upper
    WHERE parent.id = 1
      AND
        (
          SELECT COUNT(*)
          FROM product_category node
          WHERE child.lower BETWEEN node.lower AND node.upper
            AND node.lower BETWEEN parent.lower AND parent.upper
        ) = 2 
  `)
  .then(categories => {
    if (categories.rows.length) {
      const categoryPromises = categories.rows.map(category => {
        return db.raw(`
          SELECT child.id, child.name, child.path
          FROM product_category parent
          JOIN product_category child
          ON child.lower BETWEEN parent.lower AND parent.upper
          WHERE parent.id = ${category.id}
          AND
            (
              SELECT COUNT(*)
              FROM product_category node
              WHERE child.lower BETWEEN node.lower AND node.upper
                AND node.lower BETWEEN parent.lower AND parent.upper
            ) = 2 
        `)
        .then(subcategories => {
          const categoryObject = { ...category, subcategories: [] }
          if (subcategories.rows.length) {
            subcategories.rows.map(subcategory => {
              categoryObject.subcategories.push(subcategory)
            })
            products.push(categoryObject)
          } else {
            res.status(400).json("No subcategories")
          }
        })
      })

      return Promise.all(categoryPromises)
      .then(() => res.json(products))

    } else {
      res.status(400).json("No categories")
    }
  })
}
```

I have no problem getting the response but the ordering of the first level of objects inside the array is not consistent. Sometimes it is like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 9,
    "name": "Other Products",
    "path": "other_products",
    "subcategories": [
      {
        "id": 10,
        "name": "Slides",
        "path": "slides"
      },
      {
        "id": 11,
        "name": "Buoys",
        "path": "buoys"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Boats",
    "path": "boats",
    "subcategories": [
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Rescue Boats",
        "path": "rescue_boats"
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Dive Boats",
        "path": "dive_boats"
      },
      {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "Tamarans",
        "path": "tamarans"
      },
      {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "Dragon Boats",
        "path": "dragon_boats"
      },
      {
        "id": 7,
        "name": "Kayaks",
        "path": "kayaks"
      },
      {
        "id": 8,
        "name": "Speedboats",
        "path": "speedboats"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Or like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Boats",
    "path": "boats",
    "subcategories": [
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Rescue Boats",
        "path": "rescue_boats"
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Dive Boats",
        "path": "dive_boats"
      },
      {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "Tamarans",
        "path": "tamarans"
      },
      {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "Dragon Boats",
        "path": "dragon_boats"
      },
      {
        "id": 7,
        "name": "Kayaks",
        "path": "kayaks"
      },
      {
        "id": 8,
        "name": "Speedboats",
        "path": "speedboats"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 9,
    "name": "Other Products",
    "path": "other_products",
    "subcategories": [
      {
        "id": 10,
        "name": "Slides",
        "path": "slides"
      },
      {
        "id": 11,
        "name": "Buoys",
        "path": "buoys"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

How do I make it consistent? Maybe it is a bit trivial but it's getting a bit annoying after a while. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[I also asked](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/b22hwb/order_of_array_content_is_not_consistent_in_json/) in [r/learnprogramming](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/) subreddit to increase the chances of it getting answered. User [u/shhh-quiet](https://www.reddit.com/user/shhh-quiet) gave a [nice solution](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/b22hwb/order_of_array_content_is_not_consistent_in_json/eipy1rj/).

Basically, it is because I've written bad code on my snippet. I'll just quote his whole answer:

> I think it's that you're building the products array from inside the
>   nested queries' promise chain. Depending on how long the queries take,
>   products will end up with different orderings.
>
> This is generally considered bad when working with promises. It
>   basically breaks free of the ordering otherwise established by your
>   use of map and Promise.all.
>
> You should change:
>
> ```
> products.push(categoryObject)
> ```
>
> ...to:
>
> ```
> return categoryObject
> ```
>
> And change:
>
> ```
> return Promise.all(categoryPromises)
>   .then(() => res.json(products))
> ```
>
> ...to:
>
> ```
> return Promise.all(categoryPromises)
>   .then(products => res.json(products))
> ```
>
> And remove:
>
> ```
> const products = []
> ```

Edit: Just to be clear, he doesn't have a StackOverflow account and he gave me permission to post his answer.